# How to show all cart items in phtml file Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, phtml

> What is the best way to show all the items/products that are in checkout/cart in a PHTML page?

I have added a **custom phtml page** that shows some products, and also have a phtml page that want to show all the products that the visitor/user have added to cart.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product via `quoteItem` in `Cart`. Use this code below:

```
protected $cart;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
}
```

Use this code to get the product list:

```
$quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
$allItems = $quote->getAllItems();

foreach($allItems as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();                
}
```

Maybe you can use `productRepository` to load product by id:

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository

$product = $productRepository->getById($item->getProduct()->getId());
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but where should I put the code:
protected $cart;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
}

At which file?
p.s. dont forget its magento 2

Comment: You can add that code inside the `__construct` function of your Block file. After that, create a function that return the list of Item. And in the `phtml` file, you can call the `foreach` to get the list item and get the product.

Comment: I have added that code to /app/code/company/theme/Block/Template.php and im getting this error:
Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::$cart in /home/user/public_html/20189/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php on line 110

Comment: Seem like you have defined the `$cart` is `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. Change it to `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart`

Comment: Hello,

I tried to put the code at: /vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php and I receive this error: Error filtering template: Class Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart does not exist

Can you please help me at which file should I put the code ?

Thank you

Comment: Oh no. You have a phtml file to show all the item right? And you have to put the code to the Block file which provide the `$block` variable that you use in the phtml file

Comment: I haven't used any code to show all items that are in cart (or any user who adds the products to cart), and I have used many codes there, but no luck. So I have nothing there

Comment: which phtml file you want to show the item?

Comment: I have created a phtml file and have put it to show from a page in magento, so when i go to mysite.com/buynow it shows my phtml code file (have put there some products to add to cart) and in the right side have the cart so when a user add the product to cart, it will show the cart details, like product info, price etc. That's what I want to do there

Comment: You want to show the item in a single page or in a section inside the page.

Comment: in a section inside the page (that is builded with phtml), but anyway I think is the same thing

Comment: which Block file you are using to render within that phtml?

Comment: im not using anything, I haven't done anything for the cart (to show the items)